# Passing a value created on the server-side to router.options.ts in Nuxt v3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to grab a header from an incoming request, and use it's value within `router.options.ts`.

I'm looking through the Nuxt v3 docs and trying to figure out how best to go about this. It feels like I should be using server middleware to catch the header value, but where do I store it so that it is accessible within `router.options.ts`?

Eg.

```
/server/middleware/example.ts

export default defineEventHandler((context) => {
  context.example = 'value'
})
```

```
/router.options.ts

export default <RouterConfig> {
  routes: (_routes) => {
    const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp()

    if (nuxtApp.ssrContext?.event.context.example) {
      console.log("example is available")
    } else {
      console.log("example is not available")
    }
  }
}
```

In the example above, I get `example is available` initially, but then `example is not available` on the client-side. I've tried a few other approaches, but can't seem to get it. I'm not sure at which point(s) in the app lifecycle `router.options.ts` is called, and how to hook in beforehand to set my header value.

I found this example, which looks similar to what I'm trying to achieve- except the author has a fallback value for when the server-side value is not available, which is not what I'm looking for.

https://github.com/zernonia/keypress/blob/main/app/router.options.ts

Answer (score 1):

I've found what I was looking for, posting here in case anyone else needs the answer.

https://nuxt.com/docs/examples/composables/use-state

The `useState` composable is `an SSR-friendly ref replacement`, which keeps it's value after server-side rendering. So I can make use of it in my own composable, and pass the value from the server to the client.

```
/composables/host.ts

export const useHost = () => useState<string>('host', () => useDefaultHost().value)

export const useDefaultHost = (fallback = 'fallbackhost') => {
  const host = ref(fallback)
  if (process.server) {
    const hostFromHeaders = useRequestHeaders()['host']
    if (hostFromHeaders ) {
      host.value = hostFromHeaders 
    }
  }
  return host
}
```

And in `router.options.ts`

```
import type { RouterConfig } from '@nuxt/schema'
import {useHost} from "~/composables/host";

export default <RouterConfig> {
  routes: (_routes) => {
    const host = useHost().value
    let pagesDir = ''

    if (host.includes('valueA')) {
      pagesDir = 'pageDirA'
    }
    if (host.includes('valueB')) {
      pagesDir = 'pageDirB'
    }

    let routes = _routes.filter((route) => {
      return (typeof route.name === 'string' && route.name.includes(pagesDir))
    })
    _routes.forEach((route) => {
      route.path = route.path.replace(`/${pagesDir}`, '')
    })

    return routes
  }
}
```